# FormGroup binding error in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-modules

Please, I'm stuck here guys ; I've got this error a day later and it is driving me crazy while developing an `Angular2` application (**stable version**) :

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'FormGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. 
("<form name="pageForm" 
[ERROR ->][FormGroup]="pageForm" 
class="lc-edit-page" novalidate>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6"")
```

The weird part that when searching around, there is an obvious only one solution which is doing in

**`import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`**

in the `Module file`. I did it :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { UsersListComponent } from './modals';
import { LcFormComponent } from './lc-form';
import { AddUComponent } from      '../../../../+u/shared/components';

import { UIRouterModule } from 'ui-router-ng2';
import { TranslateModule } from 'ng2-translate';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LcFormComponent,
    UsersListComponent
  ],
  imports:       [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    UIRouterModule,
    TranslateModule,
    LcFormComponent,
    UsersListComponent,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers:     [],
  exports:       [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    UIRouterModule,
    TranslateModule,
    LcFormComponent,
    UsersListComponent,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  entryComponents:
  [
    AddUComponent,
    UsersListComponent

  ]
})
export class ParModule {}
```

The binding error is in the HTML of `LcFormComponent`, in other components it works smoothly but here i really did not know where is the problem. 
Here is the `LcFormComponent.ts` importing part:

```
import { Input, Component, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

import * as lodash from 'lodash';
import { TranslateService } from 'ng2-translate';
import { NotificationsService } from 'angular2-notifications';
import { NgbModal, NgbModalRef, NgbModalOptions } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { UsersListComponent }      from '../modals';
import { AddUComponent }        from '../../../../../+users/shared/components/modals';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lc-form',
  templateUrl: './lc-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lc-form.component.scss']
})
export class LcPageComponent {

// ....

}
```

Any help Please ?

Comment: Did you mean `[formGroup]="..."`?

Comment: yes , Exactly it is [formGroup]

Comment: Did you use lower case `[formGroup]` or upper case `[FormGroup]` in html?

Comment: Man , put it as an answer , I'll check it , you made my day , thank you very much ! @ulubeyn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `[FormGroup]` in html, which should be `[formGroup]` instead.